# Trying to understand Delphi mov ebx, eax in a binary file

Tags: delphi, x86

I'm trying to reverse engineer some code that was used to read a hex file and a football roster file for xbox 360.

Can you someone who is familiar with Delphi help me understand what the below code is doing exactly?  I believe it's grabbing offsets from a hex file and then creating pointers of some sort to pull the first and last name.

I've pasted the entire procedure in here, but I'm primarily focusing on the FirstName and LastName sections.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Javo

```
procedure TEditPlayerMain._PROC_00697780(Sender : TObject);
begin
(*
00697780   53                     push    ebx
00697781   8BD8                   mov     ebx, eax
00697783   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.FirstNameTxt : TcxTextEdit
|
00697785   8B83AC030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$03AC]
0069778B   8B08                   mov     ecx, [eax]

* Possible reference to virtual method TcxTextEdit.OFFS_64
|
0069778D   FF5164                 call    dword ptr [ecx+$64]

* Possible String Reference to: 'Multi'
|
00697790   BA40786900             mov     edx, $00697840

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.FirstNameTxt : TcxTextEdit
|
00697795   8B83AC030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$03AC]

* Reference to: Controls.TControl.SetText(TControl;TCaption);
|
0069779B   E874CEDDFF             call    00474614
006977A0   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.LastNameTxt : TcxTextEdit
|
006977A2   8B83A8030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$03A8]
006977A8   8B08                   mov     ecx, [eax]

* Possible reference to virtual method TcxTextEdit.OFFS_64
|
006977AA   FF5164                 call    dword ptr [ecx+$64]

* Possible String Reference to: 'Player'
|
006977AD   BA50786900             mov     edx, $00697850

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.LastNameTxt : TcxTextEdit
|
006977B2   8B83A8030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$03A8]

* Reference to: Controls.TControl.SetText(TControl;TCaption);
|
006977B8   E857CEDDFF             call    00474614

* Possible String Reference to: 'Multi Player'
|
006977BD   BA60786900             mov     edx, $00697860

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.lblPlayerName : TLabel
|
006977C2   8B8300030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$0300]

* Reference to: Controls.TControl.SetText(TControl;TCaption);
|
006977C8   E847CEDDFF             call    00474614
006977CD   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.cbJersey : TcxComboBox
|
006977CF   8B83A4030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$03A4]
006977D5   8B08                   mov     ecx, [eax]

* Possible reference to virtual method TcxComboBox.OFFS_64
|
006977D7   FF5164                 call    dword ptr [ecx+$64]
006977DA   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.numLabel : TLabel
|
006977DC   8B8388030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$0388]
006977E2   8B08                   mov     ecx, [eax]

* Reference to method TLabel.SetEnabled(Boolean)
|
006977E4   FF5164                 call    dword ptr [ecx+$64]
006977E7   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.lblJersey : TLabel
|
006977E9   8B8328030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$0328]

* Reference to: Controls.TControl.SetText(TControl;TCaption);
|
006977EF   E820CEDDFF             call    00474614
006977F4   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.lblPosition : TLabel
|
006977F6   8B8324030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$0324]

* Reference to: Controls.TControl.SetText(TControl;TCaption);
|
006977FC   E813CEDDFF             call    00474614
00697801   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.lblWeight : TLabel
|
00697803   8B8350030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$0350]

* Reference to: Controls.TControl.SetText(TControl;TCaption);
|
00697809   E806CEDDFF             call    00474614
0069780E   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.lblHeight : TLabel
|
00697810   8B834C030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$034C]

* Reference to: Controls.TControl.SetText(TControl;TCaption);
|
00697816   E8F9CDDDFF             call    00474614
0069781B   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.tsAttributes : TcxTabSheet
|
0069781D   8B8360030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$0360]

* Reference to: ComCtrls.TCustomHeaderControl.SetHotTrack(TCustomHeaderControl;Boolean);
|
00697823   E83C48F0FF             call    0059C064
00697828   33D2                   xor     edx, edx

* Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.tsAbilities : TcxTabSheet
|
0069782A   8B8368030000           mov     eax, [ebx+$0368]

* Reference to: ComCtrls.TCustomHeaderControl.SetHotTrack(TCustomHeaderControl;Boolean);
|
00697830   E82F48F0FF             call    0059C064
00697835   5B                     pop     ebx
00697836   C3                     ret

*)
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I'm not particularly "familiar with Delphi". But I understand quite well what's happening, so do read on.

> I believe it's (1) grabbing offsets from a hex file and then (2) creating pointers of some sort to (3) pull the first and last name.

That is entirely, completely, and utterly the wrong way to look at it. None of your 3 assumptions appear to be correct. Sorry.

There is only *one* occurrence of `mov ebx, eax`, and it's right at the top. Its purpose is to safeguard the *initial value* of `eax`, which is important in Delphi-assembly, as it holds a pointer to an instance of the class that calls this code.

Since `eax` gets used in other ways as well (typically, it will hold a return value from calling another function), the compiler stores this right away into another register -- here `ebx`, although the compiler is free to pick any free one, or even store it temporarily on a local stack.

Your class is called `TEditPlayerMain`, and this decompiler¹ recognizes `ebx` gets used as a Class in a couple of lines -- the ones with comments "Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.xxx". Those are class member variables that are referenced by name, and stored in the positions pointed to *by* `ebx`: `[ebx+$034C]`, for instance, points to `TEditPlayerMain.lblHeight`.

Another typical use, which does not appear in this fragment, is that the initial value allows access to the *Virtual Method Table* of the class, the full list of functions that were defined for it. This table is pointed to by the first value, `[ebx]`, and so code to 'call' the second method in the VMT would be something like

```
mov eax, [ebx]
call dword ptr [eax+4]
```

You can see variants of this code in your lines

```
006977A0   33D2                   1. xor     edx, edx
006977A2   8B83A8030000           2. mov     eax, [ebx+$03A8]
006977A8   8B08                   3. mov     ecx, [eax]
006977AA   FF5164                 4. call    dword ptr [ecx+$64]
```

1. Zero out `edx` -- this is the argument of the following function call.
2. Load `eax` with a pointer to a class object inside your class.
3. Load `ecx` with the VMT pointer for that object.
4. Call function #$64 of that object.

Now where do you see references to "first and last names"? Only as class member *variables*:

`Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.FirstNameTxt : TcxTextEdit`

and

`Reference to control TEditPlayerMain.LastNameTxt : TcxTextEdit`

These are *controls* inside the window or dialog that *happen* to bear the names 'FirstNameTxt' and 'LastNameTxt'. Both are (apparently) TcxTextEdit fields, and are called first with some  `function_X(0)`, then

```
TControl.SetText(FirstNameTxt, 'Multi')
...
TControl.SetText(LastNameTxt,'Player')
```

I don't know what this dialog looks like, but I *think* it's two text edit fields with a header, and the headers are set to 'Multi' and 'Player'. The `function_X(0)` might very well be to clear the contents of the text field.

So this code does *not* 'grab offsets from a hex file' (all of that "hex" stuff is actually something defined inside this single class), it does *not* create pointers (it merely fetches some, to class member objects inside this single class), and it doesn't handle "first and last name", other than there happen to be some member variables named as such.

---

¹ But it's nicely commented output anyway. This doesn't seem native asm code created by Delphi itself, so which decompiler did you use?